# Неверная локализация «качества» знака

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нет-в-transifex

Ошибка в локализации на [странице профиля](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=topactivity):

[image: скриншот]

Если в профиле по ссылке нажать на отслеживаемый знак, появляется поп-ап с ошибочным текстом наподобие такого: «тематический значок Bronze локализация».

Эта строка [в транзифексе](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40840518?qt=%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA) выглядит как `$badgeClass$ $tag$ tag badge` и переводится как `тематический знак $badgeClass$ $tag$`. Это означает, что подставляемый текст для `$badgeClass$` — Bronze — не переведён. Поскольку я не нашёл непереведённого Bronze в транзифексе, это должен быть баг движка.

Comment: может быть, стоит поставить метку *нет-в-transifex*?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Это где-то на границе. С обной стороны, обе строки вроде бы есть в транзифексе. С другой стороны, там-то ошибки точно нету.

Comment: Строку разработчики добавили, но сделали это криво. Завел отдельный баг: [Не хватает строк множественного числа для цветов знака](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2398)